# Is ResizeObserver API necessary or preferred in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, resize-observer

We can already detect dimension change by using ref and useEffect in React:

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("height changed to", ref.current?.clientHeight)
}, [ref.current?.clientHeight])
```

I wonder what is the advantage of ResizeObserver over this ref + useEffect approach? I'm surprised there's no online discussion around this, given ResizeObserver has been there for awhile since 2018. I can see if you're using Vanilla Javascript then ResizeObserver might be the best way to get dynamic height.

But in React I just don't understand how ResizeObserver API is better. I tested both and in Chrome both fire updates almost at the same time. I researched online and many are talking about how to use React Hook with ResizeObserver, but rarely do these posts talk about ref + useEffect already suffice.

Does anyone know if using React, any advantage using ResizeObserver API, or it really doesn't differ much from ref + useEffect approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> We can already detect dimension change by using ref and useEffect in React:

For a useEffect to run, the component must be rendering. For the component to be rendering, something somewhere must have set state. So if all of that is happening, then yes, your effect can notice the size has changed since the previous render.

But if nothing sets state, then none of that will happen. Maybe you're getting lucky, and some component happens to be setting state around the time the size changes, but that's not something you should rely on. If you delete some random component, or try to optimize performance by skipping rendering, you can suddenly break your resize "detection" code.

The point of the resize observer is to get *notified* that the change has happened. Then you can set state, and cause the rerender. So now instead of hoping a rerender happens, you *know* it will happen.

Comment: Sorry I don't quite get your point, I think I need an example to see where a `ResizeObserver` is fired but `useEffect(...[ref.current.clientHeight])` doesn't fire.  I do get the part if you do `<SomeChild height={ref.current.clientHeight}` it won't update SomeChild when clientHeight changes, a state is needed like `useState` to store the height. But isn't `ResizeObserver` the same? It'll need a set state in its ResizeObserverCallback. The ref+useEffect approach we'll set state in `useEffect(() => {setHeight()}, [ref.current?.clientHeight])`

Comment: I think it's an important topic to clarify, like you said if `ref + useEffect` is not reliable to detect resize, that's a big issue and I better use `ResizeObserver`. But seems they only differ in special occasions like you mentioned skipping rendering?  I'm interested in learning more, so there's a case resize happened and we skip rendering for performance, so useEffect(...[ref.current.clientHeight]) won't trigger. But if a resize happens won't that intrinsically means re-render happened? I'm confused.

Comment: `I think I need an example to see where a ResizeObserver is fired but useEffect(...[ref.current.clientHeight]) doesn't fire.` Have a single component in your app, with a div styled to 100% the width of the window. Then use your mouse to resize the window. If you are not listening to a resize observer, then your component will not render.

Comment: Here's the use effect + ref version: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-gfkt6c?file=src%2FApp.js Here's the resize observer version: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-d6bsyb?file=src/App.js . Open up the console, then resize the window. The use ref one will not rerender (as indicated by there being no additional log statements), while the resize observer one will.

Comment: `The ref+useEffect approach we'll set state in useEffect(() => {setHeight()}, [ref.current?.clientHeight])` There is only one point in time where the dependency array is checked: when the component is rendering. If the client height changes at any other point in time, this line of code won't know about it, and can't do anything. So putting the call to setState inside the effect is just saying "if we're *already* rendering, render again". That won't help, since the whole problem is you need that first render. You need a piece of code that says "if event X happens (outside of rendering), render.

Comment: After re-test again, @Nicholas Tower you are absolutely right. I think in my previous test I have 3 refs, I only change 1 ref to the useEffect approach and the rest 2 refs using ResizeObserver approach. Probably the 2 refs nudged the re-rendering that's why it "looks like" the useEffect approach worked.

Comment: As a takeaway moving forward probably I should stop using `useEffect & ref.current.clientHeight` to track resize (and only doing so if I only care about initial size). As you said I might be a bit lucky previously.